# Document download if it cannot be displayed

Tags: html

I want to be able to display objects that students submit to our learning system. They submit different types of objects - word documents, videos, PDF docs, photos etc. The work is stored on Amazon S3 and we use the URL to display the items using a variable {DocURL}

We have our display code as:

```
<video width="100%" height="600" controls="controls">
  <source src="{DocURL}" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="{DocURL}" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="{DocURL}" type="video/webm" />
<object data="{DocURL}" width="100%" height="600">
<embed src="{DocURL}" width="100%" height="600">
Your document will download
</embed>
</object>
</video>
```

This works great if the work object is video, PDF or photo. The issue I have is that Microsoft office documents will not display so I want to force them to be automatically downloaded instead. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try iframe tag to display your ms-office files

```
<iframe src="{DocURL}"></iframe>
```